# Graphics on retina 13 which only booted in osx safe mode

Tags: release-juno, macbook, intel

Previous to Juno, my retina 13 got some liquid spilled. I cleaned it then the service said they didn't know how to fix it - it boots only in safe mode on osx.

So I installed Juno , (I manage to enter GUI via grub cmdline option nomodeset. If I remove it - I have graphics artefacts and it's unusable)

inxi says:

```
Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: N/A
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: fbdev,intel unloaded: modesetting,vesa
resolution: 2560x1600~93Hz
OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 19.0.2
```

So I guess it's running a non-accelerated framebuffer driver, I have only 1 resolution (2560x1600), pixel doubled (1280x800) or not, no brightness control. Fullhd works acceptably well although high cpu on Chrome.

I tried adding some other resolutions via cvt and xrandr add mode/new mode, also xorg.conf, but once I switch to them nothing happens.

Here is the output of xrandr:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 2560 x 1600, current 2560 x 1600, maximum 2560 x 1600
default connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
2560x1600 93.00*
```

if I enable modesetting driver it's unusable, lots of artefacts and it crashes - I enabled it via xorg.conf file by specifying driver "modesetting" - system is up to date.

I also installed the intel driver via Device Driver Manager app from Linux Mint but it appears X crashes (not sure here)

The question is how can I add some other resolution and go about the brightness control via fbdev driver or other options to make the best use of this laptop (as I can't use it anymore under OSX apparently)

Thanks in advance and nice distro.

Some other details: 
My xorg.0.log file (graphic related stuff) :

[Link](https://gist.github.com/florin0x01/13e9d43c75bd1aa9e24a1d3d7aeb5fc1)

My xorg conf file situated in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf (Although I don't think it affects anything) : [Link](https://gist.github.com/florin0x01/1f962e912b72d54d9384ff2a7b9bcb1a)

[EDIT]: Also tried installing an updated driver via [http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/01/install-mesa-18-2-8-ppa-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/](http://Mesa%2018.2.8%20link) but it's unusable (black screen with artifacts). I think it is a hardware problem but how do I go around it, namely to have multiple resolutions + brightness adjust, even with the fbdev driver if no other options?